# org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/ core/env/Environment

Tags: spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I get the error in my XML when I add the following line -

```
xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
```

Error occured processing XML: `'org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;'.`

I am using

```
spring-data-elasticsearch-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar
```

And all other spring jars like *spring-beans, spring-context, spring-core,* ...etc of 4.0.2 version.
Are these versions compatible with *spring-data-elasticsearch* ?

could you please suggest.

Comment: I am using spring-data-elasticsearch apis. When I call count() method on the 

org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.count() , 
ElasticsearchRepository.count()....

it throws NullPointerException..

I checked elasticsearch is working. But still gettting this error.  Please suggest what can be done..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

***Spring Data ElasticSearch*** Requires Minimum ***Spring 4.2.5 Release***

You are getting this error because Spring 4.0.2 Does not have the getEnvironment() Method.
Change the Spring Version to the minimum ***Spring 4.2.5.Release***